# Xamarin Forms Button Content Layout Not Working

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I have a button with an arrow on the right side of it, this works great with android, but not at all with ios.

Here is the Xaml on the button:

```
<Button TextColor="White" Image="fwArrowWhite24x24" ContentLayout="Right, -10"
   Text="Test" />
```

The image comes through, it is just on the left side of the button.

How can I get the arrow to the right side  of my button?

**Edit**

I am wrapped in a DataTemplate for a Syncfusion SFSchedule. I don't know if his will help or if it does anthing, I still thought I would add that information.

Comment: have you tried removing the negative spacing?

Comment: Yeah that doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your query with “Button with right side arrow working fine in android and not in iOS” and we have created the sample using Xamarin forms button and it is working fine in our sample. We have attached sample for the same.

Please find the sample from the below link.

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/212747/ze/Button2099745900.zip

Please find Screenshot from the  below link:

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/212747/ze/ScreenShot-1953420906.zip

Please let us know if you need further assistance on this.